# Mapping two list of Objects by key

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two list of objects like so :

```dart
class KeyValue {
  KeyValue({required this.key, required this.value});

  final String key;
  final String value;
}

class CustomClass {
  CustomClass({
    required this.key,
    required this.name,
    this.value,
  });

  final String key;
  final String name;
  final String? value;
}

var listCustomClass = [
  CustomClass(key: "1234", name: "name1"),
  CustomClass(key: "1234", name: "name2"),
  CustomClass(key: "12345", name: "name3"),
  CustomClass(key: "12345678", name: "name4"),
];

final listKeyValue = [
  KeyValue(key: "1234", value: "someValue1"),
  KeyValue(key: "12345", value: "someValue2"),
  KeyValue(key: "12345678", value: "someValue3"),
  KeyValue(key: "123456789", value: "someValue4"),
];
```

I'd like to **map** `listCustomClass` & `listKeyValue` by `key` in order to create
create a new `List<CustomClass>` with each `CustomClass()` taking its `value` parameter from its matching `KeyValue()` object (the one with the same `key`)

it would create `newListCustomClass` like so :

```dart
newListCustomClass = [
  CustomClass(key: "1234", name: "name1", value: "someValue1"),
  CustomClass(key: "1234", name: "name2", value: "someValue1"),
  CustomClass(key: "12345", name: "name3", value: "someValue2"),
  CustomClass(key: "12345678", name: "name4", value: "someValue3"),
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like

```dart
  String getValue(String key) =>
      listKeyValue.firstWhere((element) => element.key == key).value;

  for (int i = 0; i < listCustomClass.length; i++) {
    listCustomClass[i] =
        listCustomClass[i].copyWith(value: getValue(listCustomClass[i].key));
  }
```

And the class

```dart
class CustomClass {
  CustomClass({
    required this.key,
    required this.name,
    this.value,
  });

  final String key;
  final String name;
  final String? value;

  @override
  String toString() => 'CustomClass(key: $key, name: $name, value: $value)';

  CustomClass copyWith({
    String? key,
    String? name,
    String? value,
  }) {
    return CustomClass(
      key: key ?? this.key,
      name: name ?? this.name,
      value: value ?? this.value,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you  do I have to keep `listCustomClass` as `var` for it to be modified with the new values from your `for`  loop or can I make it `final` ? 

Comment: Yes `listCustomClass` can be final, we are modifying elements here

Comment: Note that this is O(m * n) with respect to the lengths of `listCustomClass` and `listKeyValue`.  That should be okay if the lists are small, but it will become inefficient if they're large.

Answer (score 2):

If `listCustomClass` or `listKeyValue` are large, you would be better off converting one of them to a `Map` first.  Since `listCustomClass` apparently can have elements with the same `key`, that one should stay a `List`.

```dart
  var mapKeyValue = {
    for (var keyValue in listKeyValue) keyValue.key: keyValue.value,
  };

  var newListCustomClass = [
    for (var customClass in listCustomClass)
      CustomClass(
        key: customClass.key,
        name: customClass.name,
        value: mapKeyValue[customClass.key],
      ),
  ];
```

If `listCustomClass` has *m* elements and `listKeyValues` has *n* elements, then the above code would be O(m + n).  If you store `listKeyValues` as a `Map` in the first place, then the code to convert from `List` to `Map` could be removed, and it would be just O(m).

Comment: hi thanks for your answer truth is my list is quite small & I actually have two values for each `KeyValue(key, value1, value2)` so converting them to `Map` won't work - but I will up vote : )

Comment: @Sunshine Converting to a `Map` would still work with multiple values; you'd just need the `Map` value to be a `List` of values or a `KeyValue` object itself.